# Finding the number of specific characters inside a formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to find the number of of `+`'s in a formula inside a single cell in excel.

If it were a normal cell with text inside, this would be quite easy. But due to the restrictions of the file I'm working with, I need to keep the formatting of the cell as it is.

In short:

- Cell `A1`: `=123,12+234,45+790,44`
- Cell `A2`: `=2`, as there were two +'s found in cell A1

Comment: Is a VBA solution okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [custom vba function](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/writingfunctionsinvba.aspx) (put this code in a module) :

```
Option Explicit

Function countChar(cell As Range, pattern As String)
    countChar = UBound(Split(cell.Formula, pattern))
End Function
```

And then use this function in your Worksheet :

```
=countChar(A1;"+")
```

Comment: Good timing, and very succinct hehe!

Comment: @jonsca: indeed, nice shot :)

Answer (score 2):

#### VBA

Create a function using this code:

```
Function GETFORMULA(c As Range) As String
    If c.HasArray Then
        GETFORMULA = "{" & c.Formula & "}"
    ElseIf VarType(c) = vbString And Not c.HasFormula Then
        GETFORMULA = c.Value
    Else
        GETFORMULA = c.Formula
    End If
End Function
```

The ff. formula will display the number of occurences of "+" in it.

```
=LEN(GETFORMULA(cell))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(GETFORMULA(cell),"+",""))
```

#### Non-VBA

Highlight the cells that contain formulas.  If you only need to deal with one cell, just add a `'` before the `=` and skip the next step.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. Enter `=` into the **Find what** and `'=` into **Replace With**. This will convert the formula to text.

Use this formula in a blank cell to count the number of occurences of "+".

```
=LEN(cell)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(cell,"+",""))
```

To revert the cells back to the way they were, highlight them, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and replace `'=` with `=`. Doing so will cause the formula above to show 0.

Answer (score 1):

This function will take the formula of the cell that is passed to it (that is you'd call it by `=NumPlus(A1)` on your worksheet) and walk along it and count the plus signs.  You could modify it slightly to take a character that you want to count as an argument.

```
Option Explicit
Function NumPlus(cel As Variant) As Variant
    Dim formstr As String
    Dim i As Integer

    NumPlus = 0
    formstr = cel.Formula

    For i = 1 To Len(formstr)
        If Mid(formstr, i, 1) = "+" Then
            NumPlus = NumPlus + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```